# Mysql DELETE Where 1=1 AND 2=2

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is get an SQL command to delete if 2 factors are there IE

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE unique_id = "************" & world_id = "1"
```

World ID's 1-5 I want to be able to delete if unique id and world id are there.

It may be easy but my search terms might not be correct, Sorry If this is something easy that is just escaping me.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error, It just does not do anything.

Comment: Can you give us a non-working query you tried and a related sample of your data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what error or incorrect results you are getting.  But, you are using `&` which is not correct, because it is bit-wise and.  You want logic and, so use `and`:

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE unique_id = '************' AND world_id = '1';
```

Also, it is better to use single quotes for string (and date) constants.